# Static to BGP redistribition

Tags: configuration, router, packet, cisco, bgp

how to redistribute static routes in bgp?
What is the configuration to be able to do this in packet tracer? Can you give an example in another way. Thank you.

Can you help me ??

Comment: Please provide a bit more context to your question, also you could post what you already tried and why it's not working. This encourages people to answer, as they have a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

copied this from a running configuration - for my experience it's best practice to use a route-map which avoids redistributing *any* static route.

Redistributed routes should be permitted explicitly:

```
conf t

ip prefix-list PL_STATIC seq 5 permit 10.10.10.0/24
ip prefix-list PL_STATIC seq 10 permit 10.10.11.00/24

route-map RM_STATIC permit 10
 match ip address prefix-list PL_STATIC

router bgp 65535
  redistribute static route-map RM_STATIC

end
```

Verify your redistribution using

```
show ip bgp
```

And - be patient with BGP it's designed for stability, not for quick reactions.

And - only "active" static routes get redistributed, they have to show up in your routing-table as "S"tatic-routes:

```
show ip route
```